# How to filter some numerical values from an array?

Tags: php

I have an array `$myArray1` with some numerical values like `2 5 7 13 23 25`
Another array `$myArray2` has numerical values like `3 4 7 11 13 25`

My requirement is to get a third array `$myArray3` having only those values of `$myArray1` that are not present in `$myArray2 i.e. 2 5 23`

Please tell me any function of php for this?

Comment: Hav you tried `array_diff()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $myArray1=[2,5,7,13,23,25];
    $myArray2=[3,4,7,11,13,25];
    $myArray3=array_diff($myArray1,$myArray2);
    var_dump($myArray3); // 2, 5, 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_diff. The documentation can be found [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
array_diff($myArray1, $myArray2);
```

Thanks