# How to obtain values of an array of strings that are not present in another array of strings?

Tags: php

I have an array `$myArray1` with some string values like `2 5 7 13 23 25`. Another array `$myArray2` has string values like `2 4 7 11 13 25`.

My requirement is to get a third array `$myArray3` having only those values of `$myArray1` that are not present in `$myArray2` i.e. `5 23`.

I have tried `$myArray3 = array_diff($myArray1, $myArray2)` but then `$myArray3[0]` displays *Undefined offset: 0*.

Please tell me, is there any function of PHP for this?

Comment: First, they aren't strings but integers. Second, it sounds like homework

Comment: Didn't we answer this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673354/how-to-filter-some-numerical-values-from-an-array/41673441#41673441 ?

Comment: Lets suppose they are stored as strings.

Comment: `array_diff` doesn't reset keys, so you get `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: `$myArray3 = array_values(array_diff($myArray1, $myArray2))` to get rid of the Undefined Message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter some numerical values from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673354/how-to-filter-some-numerical-values-from-an-array)

Comment: If values are numerical, $myArray3[0] works fine. If values are string, $myArray3[0] doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_diff` doesn't reset keys, so you get `Undefined offset: 0`. If you want them to reset you need to use `array_values`.

```
$myArray3 = array_values(array_diff($myArray1, $myArray2));
```

Answer (score 0):

array_diff does not changes the index of the unique values. you can use array_values function to reset the indexes of result array.

try this

```
 $result = array_values(array_diff($array , $array2));
 print_r($result);
```